# What is the in-line assembly code for kernel preemption and disable interrupts?

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt, inline-assembly

I know that in kernel I can call `get_cpu()` to disable kernel preemption and `local_irq_save(flags)` to disable interrupt. I'm curious how can I still achieve the same goal without calling these functions. I have three questions,

1. I found that `cli` instruction is the one responsible for disabling interrupts. Therefore, I was wondering if the following in-line assembly,

   ```
   asm volatile("cli": : :"memory");
   ```

is enough to disable interrupts. If It works, how can I check if it actually disables interrupts?

2. Is there any inline assembly instruction that I can use to disable kernel preemption?
3. I know it is not possible to disable interrupts from the userspace. I just wondering if somehow someone manages to run that `cli` instruction from the userspace. Will it still be able to disable the interrupts? If the answer is no then why?

Comment: Yes, cli in the kernel will disable interrupts. But you should use the defined function instead. Cli in user code will not execute; it causes a GP fault.

Comment: note: CLI cannot disable NMI, nor user generated interrupts. If you are learning OS: you should have a tiny boot loader with your test code. You can test there (by generating hardware interrupts, e.g. clock/alarm, USB, ...). "Kernel preemption" is "kernel", not CPU, so there is no instruction for this, it is just a task of kernel, and you just tell the kernel not to change CPU. For details, look the Intel manuals (the volume about OS for ia32 architecture). Very detailed, but you need to read it at lease twice, before things start to make sense.

Comment: You can set the IO privilege level separately from the normal privilege level, so you can be in ring 3 and still be able to execute `cli` if you have iopl=0.  In Linux, see the `iopl` system call.  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/iopl.2.html

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi are you talking about `clts` instruction from intel manuals?

Comment: @PeterCordes is context switching will happen if the interrupt is disabled?

Comment: Only an NMI could give control back to the kernel.  That could happen via a performance-counter interrupt, e.g. the kernel uses one for an NMI watchdog by default.  It's generally a bad idea to leave interrupts disabled in user-space for a long time, though.  I don't know exactly what will happen.  Linux is *not* designed for it.  e.g. RCU on other cores will get stuck in `RUN_ON` trying to run itself on this core via an IPI.

Comment: If you want to have a CPU to yourself, you might want to look into the `isolcpus=1` Linux kernel boot option.